# Error mapping many to many in nhibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Hy,
I have this c# code:

```
 var criteria = GetSession().CreateCriteria<Indicatore>();

 List<string> dpsirs  //passed as a parameter

 // I want to select all [indicatore] that have [dpsrir] in my list dpsirs
 if (dpsirs.Count > 0) {
   criteria.CreateCriteria("IndicatoriDpsir", "Dpsir", JoinType.InnerJoin);
   criteria.Add(Restrictions.In("Dpsir.Dpsir", dpsirs)); 
 }
```

When I select data

```
var indicatori = criteria.List<Indicatore>();
```

I have this error:

```
Exception occurred getter of Mappings.Dpsir.DpsirId
Object does not match target type.
```

My mapping class are:

```
public class Indicatore {
....
public virtual IList<IndicatoreDpsir> IndicatoriDpsir { get; set; }
....
}

public class IndicatoreMap : ClassMap<Indicatore> {
....
this.HasMany(x => x.IndicatoriDpsir).KeyColumn("INDICATORE_PFK");
}

public class IndicatoreDpsir {
  public virtual Indicatore Indicatore { get; set; }
  public virtual Dpsir Dpsir { get; set; }
}

public class IndicatoreDpsirMap : ClassMap<IndicatoreDpsir> 
  public IndicatoreDpsirMap() {
   Table("R_INDICATORI_DPSIR");
   LazyLoad();
   CompositeId()
   .KeyReference(x => x.Indicatore, "INDICATORE_PFK")
   .KeyReference(x => x.Dpsir, "DPSIR_PID");
  }
}

public class Dpsir {    
  public Dpsir() {
    IndicatoriDpsir = new List<IndicatoreDpsir>();
  }    
  public virtual string DpsirId { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<IndicatoreDpsir> IndicatoriDpsir { get; set; }
  public virtual string DescrizioneIt { get; set; }
  public virtual string DescrizioneFr { get; set; } 
}

public class DpsirMap : ClassMap<Dpsir> {    
 public DpsirMap() {
  Table("D_DPSIR");
  LazyLoad();
  Id(x => x.DpsirId).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Column("DPSIR_ID");
  Map(x => x.DescrizioneIt).Column("DESCRIZIONE_IT").Not.Nullable().Length(128);
  Map(x => x.DescrizioneFr).Column("DESCRIZIONE_FR").Not.Nullable().Length(128);
  HasMany(x => x.IndicatoriDpsir).KeyColumn("DPSIR_PID");
 }
}
```

**Note**

The strange thing is that I have an identical situation that works. The only 2 differences are that in my class Dpsir the key is type of **string** (and not **int**) and is Assigned (and not Identity)

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Sara

Comment: can you try `"Dpsir.Dpsir.DpsirId", dpsirs.Select(d => d.Dpsir).ToArray()`?

Comment: @Firo - Thanks for reply. I just resolved now. The solution is (as you suggest) replace `"Dpsir.Dpsir"` with `"Dpsir.Dpsir.DpsirId"`. Because the key is type of **string**. If key is type of Int it is not necessary specify the key column!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specify the id explicitly in the restriction: `"Dpsir.Dpsir.DpsirId", dpsirs.Select(d => d.DpsirId).ToArray()`

Comment: In my code it was not necessary put `dpsirs.Select(d => d.DpsirId).ToArray()`. Was sufficient put `"Dpsir.Dpsir.DpsirId"`